# Deep linking:different behaviour on different ios devices?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, deep-linking

My question is that i have embedded deep linking in my ios application. It is successfully opening my ios app from facebook app on iPhone 5c but it is not working on iPhone 6 plus,it is just redirecting to app store while my app is installed in the device.

Can someone tell me why there is difference of behaviour of deep linking on different devices.

Both the devices have same version 9.3.2

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can't tell you much without an error message.

Comment: behaviour can be different bacause of different iOS versions on devices.

Comment: Hi @Droppy it is not giving an error it is just redirecting to app store while my app is installed in device.

Comment: check your iphone 6 plus fb application existed or not?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Universal Links for this, it's possible you inadvertently disabled them on one of the devices. Try pasting the link into your default iOS Notes app, long-pressing on it, and selecting **Open in [app]**

Comment: hi Alex thanku for your response, i m using this https://qa.streamxxx.com/home/share?shared_id=5&shared_by=user&shared_on=default&shared_from=ios link, is this universal link?

Comment: Hi there. It appears not. If it were, there would be a file at https://qa.streamxxx.com/apple-app-site-association